# Rails Activerecord Ambiguous column name on .joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here is my code. It work fine if I have something in the :search field or if I have something in the :supplier field but if I have something in both i get "Ambiguous column name 'NUMBER'". Is there a way to select AS or something?

```
@date_from = params[:date_from]  ||     Date.today.beginning_of_month.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
@date_to = params[:date_to] ||  Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
q = "%#{params[:search]}%"

@products = Product.where("DISCONT = ? AND NONPRODUCT = ?" ,0,0)
@products = @products.where('NUMBER like ?' ,q) if params[:search].present?
@products = @products.joins(:supplier_items).where('SUPPLIER = ?' ,params[:supplier]) if params[:supplier].present?
@products = @products.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just prefix the number with the table name

For example:

```
@products = Product.where(:discount => 0, :nonproduct => 0)
@products = @products.where('products.number like ?', query)
```

Comment: Thats what I thought but when I add products. I get the following error:         " TinyTds::Error: The multi-part identifier "products.NUMBER" could not be bound.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (25) [__rnt].* FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [STOCK].[STOCK_ID] ASC) AS [__rn], [STOCK].* FROM [STOCK] WHERE (DISCONT = 0 AND NONPRODUCT = 0) AND (products.NUMBER like N''%ipob%'') ) AS [__rnt] WHERE [__rnt].[__rn] > (0) ORDER BY [__rnt].[__rn] ASC'"

Comment: Is your table name stock or products?  That SQL looks like stock.

Comment: The table in the DB is STOCK but in the product model i have   self.table_name = 'STOCK'

Comment: So use ```stock.number like ?```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `suppliers` table and `products` table both have a column named "number". Honestly, you'd be best off running a migration to change the column names now (maybe `supplier_num` / `product_num`) because keeping it something as generic as "number" will likely keep causing you headaches.